# Trouble retrieving attributes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

UPDATE - please see a resolution at the end, all I need now is an explanation.
Despite searching I could not find the same question

I created a custom Viewpager and defined a custom attribute in attrs.xml

In the view pager constructor when I try and retrieve the attribute I cannot get a meaningful value. I tried using

```
abstract int     getAttributeIntValue(String namespace, String attribute, int defaultValue)
```

Return the integer value of 'attribute'.

```
public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    Log.d(Constant.TAG, "ViewPagerType:" + attrs.getAttributeUnsignedIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto","view_pager_type",9));
    Log.d(Constant.TAG, "ViewPagerType:" + attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto","view_pager_type",9));
    Log.d(Constant.TAG, "ViewPagerType:" + attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto","view_pager_type"));
    Log.d(Constant.TAG, "ViewPagerType:" + attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto","garbage"));
```

As you can see the attrs.getAttributeValue did a string but it is not meaningful to me.

This is the output from the log statements - 9 is the default if not found, I do not undertand what the @213 number is

```
ViewPagerType:9          
ViewPagerType:9          
ViewPagerType:@2131230723
ViewPagerType:null
```

This is my attrs.xml

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="AutoResizeTextView">
        <attr name="ttf_name" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="ViewPagerType">
       <attr name="view_pager_type" format="integer"/>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<org.rh.ellierides.MyViewPager xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textPager"
    app:view_pager_type="@integer/text_viewpager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="24"
    tools:context=".Main">
```

This is integer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="text_viewpager">1</integer>
    <integer name="image_viewpager">2</integer>
</resources>
```

I think I will just create two separate viewpagers but I would still like to understand this.

---

Update I found a resolution but do not understand why the first one did not work so please still answer

```
    TypedArray a = null;
    try {
        a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ViewPagerType);
        int viewpagerType = a.getInt(R.styleable.ViewPagerType_view_pager_type, 9);
        Log.d(Constant.TAG, "viewpagerType:" + viewpagerType);
    } finally {
        if (a != null) {
            a.recycle(); // ensure this is always called
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Works but as I said above please explain it to me. What are the attrs which are passed to the constructor ?

```
    TypedArray a = null;
    try {
        a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ViewPagerType);
        int viewpagerType = a.getInt(R.styleable.ViewPagerType_view_pager_type, 9);
        Log.d(Constant.TAG, "viewpagerType:" + viewpagerType);
    } finally {
        if (a != null) {
            a.recycle(); // ensure this is always called
        }
    }
```